# Hoffman and Kunze,Linear Algebra Sec 3.4 exercise 12

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> If $V$ is an $n$ - dimensional vector space over the field $F$, and let $\scr B = \{\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n\}$ be an ordered basis for $V$.
>
> There is a unique Linear Operator $T$ on $V$ such that :
>
> $$ 
> \begin{align}
> T(\alpha_j) = \alpha_{j+1}, \quad j=1, \cdots ,n-1 \quad T(\alpha_n)=0
> \end{align}
> $$
>
> (a) What is the matrix $A$ of $T$ in the ordered basis $\scr B$?
>
> (b) Prove that $T^n=0$ but $T^{n-1}\ne 0.$

My attempt: Whilst sketching out the problem for smaller $n,$ I came to the conclusion that $A$ should be defined as $A_{ij}=\delta(i,j+1)$ where $\delta$ is the kronecker delta function. i.e. , $A$ should look something like this $$\begin{pmatrix}0\cdots&&0\\I_{n-1}&&\vdots\\&&0\end{pmatrix}$$

To show (b) is equivalent to showing $A^n=0$ and $A^{n-1}\ne 0.$

I claim that the matrix $A^m$ is defined by $A^m_{ij}=\delta(i,j+m).$ This is an observation made by computing various powers of $A$. On raising the exponent, it seems as if the zero row and the zero column is marching downwards and leftwards respectively leaving their trails behind and the identity matrix sitting inside keeps on shrinking into a smaller square.

I wish to prove this claim by induction. For $m=2,$ $A^2_{ij}=\sum_n A_{ik}A_{kj}= \sum_n\delta(i,k+1)\delta(k,j+1)$ which implies $A^2_{ij}=1 \iff i=k+1$ &$k=j+1.$ Thus $A^2_{ij}=\delta(i,j+2).$

Also $A^m_{ij}=\sum_n A^{m-1}_{ik}A_{kj}= \sum_n\delta(i,k+m-1)\delta(k,j+1)$ which implies $A^m_{ij}=1 \iff i=k+m-1$ & $k=j+1.$ Thus $A^m_{ij}=\delta(i,j+m).$

Now $A^n=0$ since $i<j+n.$ But $A^{n-1}\ne 0$ since it's $(n,1)^{th}$ entry is $1.$ **QED**

> Is there any simpler way to do this? Also, is my argument correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that
$$
T^{n-1}a_1=a_n,
$$
and hence $T^{n-1}\ne 0$.

Meanwhile
$$
T^{n-k}a_k=a_n, \quad\text{and hence}\quad T^{n-k+1}a_k=0,
$$
for all $k=1,\ldots,n$. Thus $T^na_k=0$, for all $k=1,\ldots,n$, and since the $a_j$'s constitute a basis, then $T^nu=0$, for all $u\in V$, and thus $T^n=0$.