# Exercise 10, Section 3.4 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, linear-transformations

> We have seen that the linear operator $T$ on $R^2$ defined by $T(x_1, x_2) = (x_1, 0)$ is represented in the standard ordered basis by the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0\\ \end{bmatrix}$. This operator satisfies $T^2 = T$. Prove that if $S$ is a linear operator on $R^2$ such that $S^2=S$, then $S=0$, or $S=I$, or there is an ordered basis $B$ for $R^2$ such that $[S]_B = A$ (above).

There are lots of way to prove this problem. I’m trying to show, if $S\neq 0$ and $S\neq I$, then $\exists B$ ordered basis of $R^2$ such that $[S]_B=A$. So $\exists \alpha_1,\alpha_2\in \Bbb{R}^2$ such that $S(\alpha_1)\neq (0,0)$ and $S(\alpha_2)\neq \alpha_2$. **How to progress from here?**

Comment: Hint: What is $S(S(\alpha_2)-\alpha_2)$? What's a corresponding fact about $A$?

Comment: @aschepler Can you please give some more hint? Btw this problem is similar to [exercise 12 section 3.4](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2335053/861687), a linear map with certain property, then any linear operator with that property have same matrix representing linear map relative to some basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on a way from my hint:

You noted if $S \neq 0$ and $S \neq I$, we must have vectors $\alpha_1, \alpha_2 \in \mathbb{R}^2$ with $S \alpha_1 \neq 0$ and $S \alpha_2 \neq \alpha_2$. To satisfy $[S]_B = A$, the vectors $\beta_1, \beta_2 \in \mathbb{R}^2$ of $B$ must not be the zero vector, and must satisfy

$$ S \beta_1 = 1 \beta_1 + 0 \beta_2 = \beta_1 $$
$$ S \beta_2 = 0 \beta_1 + 0 \beta_2 = 0 $$

For $\beta_1$, we see $S \alpha_1 \neq 0$, and $S(S \alpha_1) = S^2 \alpha_1 = S \alpha_1$. So let's try just $\beta_1 = S \alpha_1$.

Since $S \alpha_2 \neq \alpha_2$, $S \alpha_2 - \alpha_2 \neq 0$. Applying $S$ to this difference gives

$$ S(S \alpha_2 - \alpha_2) = S^2 \alpha_2 - S \alpha_2 = S \alpha_2 - S \alpha_2 = 0 $$

So $S \alpha_2 - \alpha_2$ is a non-zero vector which $S$ maps to zero. (It's in the null space of $S$.) That's what we need from $\beta_2$, so let's try saying $\beta_2 = S \alpha_2 - \alpha_2$.

Now to check, is $(\beta_1, \beta_2)$ actually a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$? If $c_1 \beta_1 + c_2 \beta_2 = 0$, then
$$ 0 = S(c_1 \beta_1 + c_2 \beta_2) = c_1 S \beta_1 + c_2 S \beta_2 = c_1 S \beta_1 $$
and since $S \beta_1 \neq 0$, this means $c_1 = 0$. Then $c_1 0 + c_2 \beta_2 = 0$, but $\beta_2 \neq 0$ so $c_2 = 0$ also. So yes, $B = (\beta_1, \beta_2) = (S \alpha_1, S \alpha_2 - \alpha_2)$ is a basis, with $[S]_B = A$.

Comment: You’re a crazy guy! Your proof is insane. After seeing your answer, I feel like I should have done the same thing. I knew I had to use $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ info in a clever manner. I wasn’t thinking of possibility of taking basis element from image of $S$.

Answer (score 5):

If you're familiar with the idea of diagonalization, then since $S$ satisfies $S^2=S$ and is an operator on $\mathbb{R}^2$, the characteristic polynomial of $S$ is then $p(z)=z^2-z$. Since $S\neq I$ and $S\neq 0$, it must be that the minimal polynomial of $S$ is $m(z)=z(z-1)$, and hence $S$ has two eigenvalues - $0$ and  $1$ and is diagonalizable. Hence there exists an ordered basis $B$ s.t $[S]_B=A$.

Even if you're not familiar with this, we can use this as motivation to the following solution. Note that if $\ker{S}={0}$, then $S$ is an isomorphism. Therefore, for every $w\in\mathbb{R}^2$ there exists some $v\in\mathbb{R}^2$ s.t $S(v)=w$. Now: $S(w)=S^2(v)=S(v)=w$, hence $S=I$. So we must have that $\dim\ker(S)=1$ and $\dim\text{Im}(S)=1$. Now let $v_1\neq 0\in\ker(S)$ and $v_2\neq 0\in\text{Im}(S)$. I claim that $B=\{v_2,v_1\}$ is the desired basis.

Indeed, since $v_1\in\ker(S)$, $S(v_1)=0=0\cdot v_1+0\cdot v_2$. Since $v_2\in\text{Im}(S)$, I can write $v_2=S(w)$ for some $w\in\mathbb{R}^2$. But since $S^2(w)=S(w)$, we have that:$$S(v_2)=S^2(w)=S(w)=v_2=0\cdot v_1+1\cdot v_2$$
Finally we have:$$[S]_B=\begin{pmatrix}1&&0\\0&&0\end{pmatrix}$$
as desired.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I wanna ask, how did you come up with the solution? This solution IMO is a different kind of proof technique and extremely clever. You did the following: dim$(\Bbb{R}^2)=2=$dim$(N_S)+$dim$(R_S)$. Case 1: dim$(N_S)=0$ & dim$(R_S)=2$. Case 2: dim$(N_S)=1$ & dim$(R_S)=1$. Case 3: dim$(N_S)=2$ & dim$(R_S)=0$.

Comment: I don’t understand your first solution because of my background. I think saying, $v_1$ and $v_2$ are basis of $N_S$ and $R_S$, is more precise and it’s explicit. We also need to show $B=\{v_2,v_1\}$ is basis of $\Bbb{R}^2$. If $c_1\cdot v_1+c_2\cdot v_2=0$, then $S(c_1\cdot v_1+c_2\cdot v_2)$ $=S(0)=0$. Since $S$ is linear, $c_1\cdot S(v_1)+c_2\cdot S(v_2)=0$. Since $v_1\in N_S$, we have $c_1\cdot S(v_1)+c_2\cdot S(v_2)$ $=c_2\cdot S(v_2)$  $=0$. Since $v_2\in R_S$, we have $S(v_2)=v_2$. So $c_2\cdot S(v_2)=c_2\cdot v_2=0$. Thus $c_2=0$. We have $c_1\cdot v_1+c_2\cdot v_2$ $=c_1\cdot v_1=0$.

Comment: Since $v_1\neq 0$, we have $c_1=0$. Thus $c_1=c_2=0$. Hence $B=\{v_2,v_1\}$ is independent. Since $|B|=2$ and $B$ is independent, $B$ is basis of $\Bbb{R^2}$. I’m curious how to show span$(B)=\Bbb{R}^2$.

Comment: haven’t I showed $B=\{v_2,v_1\}$ is independent?

Comment: No. I don’t see a straightforward way to prove span$(B)=\Bbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @user264745 Every 2 dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is equal to $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: Ohh.. I know that result but haven’t proved it yet. I think proof is not that hard. How to find dimension of a span, dim$(\mathrm{span}(B))$?

Comment: The dimension of the span of a set B is the size of the largest subset of independent vectors.